# Return a list with reversed and captlized words from a list

Tags: python, list, loops

I am a few weeks into learning python properly and couldn't find a way to proceed from what I currently have. The question is:

> Write a function backitup(strings) which takes a list of strings as a parameter and updates that list by replacing each string with the string written in reverse with all characters in title-case. Title case means that the first letter of each word is uppercase and the rest lower-case. Hint: You will need to use the updated-list pattern, and remember you don't need to explicitly return a value.

My code so far:

```
def backitup(strings):

    for i in range(len(strings)):
        strings[i] = strings[i].lower()
        strings[i] = strings[i].reverse()
        strings[i] = strings[i].capitalize()
    return(strings)

strings = ['Right', 'SAID', 'frEd']
backitup(strings)
print(strings)
```

Test code:

```
strings = ['Right', 'SAID', 'frEd']
backitup(strings)
print(strings)
```

Should output:

```
['Thgir', 'Dias', 'Derf']
```

I am confused as to why .reverse() does not work. I have tried reversed() and [::-1] but they just reverse the list and not the letters in the words in the list. An explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: reverse does not work because this is  string. i think you are assuming it is a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reverse()` is an inbuilt method in Python programming language that reverses objects of `list` in place, **not** `string`.
Change your code to:

```
def backitup(strings):
    for i in range(len(strings)):
        strings[i] = (strings[i])[::-1].lower().capitalize() # .lower() ins't necessary
    return(strings)

strings = ['Right', 'SAID', 'frEd']
backitup(strings)
print(strings)
```

Ouput:

```
['Thgir', 'Dias', 'Derf']
```

Comment: Just two friendly points of note: 1) This can be refactored/optimised to use `for i in strings` and 2) `.lower()` is not needed; it’s redundant, as `.capitalize()` takes care of it.

Answer (score 2):

What about something short and simple like this?  It uses a really useful convention called [list comprehension](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3) which has a wide variety of uses.  One of my favourites!

```
def backitup(strings):
    return [i[::-1].capitalize() for i in strings]

backitup(strings)
```

#### Output:

```
['Thgir', 'Dias', 'Derf']
```

Comment: I like this solution best, because it doesn't change `strings` variable in-place, but returns a new list with new string-objects inside of it.

Comment: @HampusLarsson - Thanks mate; excellent observation.  That was the exact intent of the design.

Answer (score 0):

str data type in python does not have a method called 'reverse'. You can check the methods available with a data type by using dir(str). Secondly, using [::-1] will reverse your string, I am not sure why it is not the result in your case.

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is low so I cannot comment to point out things not necessary or wrong
So I will write here -

I would like to point out, your (**walrus1234**) code and ***Mee***'s answer uses `return` but actually don't use it since you are directly assigning the processed string to original position so `return` statement is useless in both codes, I assume you want to use `return` and hence you used function So I wrote the following code

More clean and compact version,

```
def backitup(strings):
    return [string[::-1].capitalize() for string in strings]

strings = ['Right', 'SAID', 'frEd']
strings = backitup(strings);
print(strings)
```

**Output:**

['Thgir', 'Dias', 'Derf']